# How to fix Android license status unknown in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ubuntu-18.04

**flutter doctor result**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.32.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

and `run: flutter doctor --android-licenses`

**show this result**

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/home/mahkoom/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

and my sdk laste update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter.io Android License Status Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758849/flutter-io-android-license-status-unknown)

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter upgrade and also upgrade your Android studio SDK  you should be fine