# How to fix 'java.lang.module.FindException: module java.se.ee not found' error when packaging my kivy application with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying package my kivy app (python3) but when i run the command `buildozer -v android debug` see this error

```
# Cwd /home/javier/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
# Command failed: /home/javier/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have this Java version

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I downloaded only sdkmanager Command line tools [from here](https://developer.android.com/studio) and put it in my root path but i don't had success.

I Saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9) a solution and i did it but i don't solve the error.

I has a virtualenv with all dependencies installed. Also i edited the `buildozer.spec` and i was custom it

The Virtualenv is:

```
(envAppSinapsis)~/AppSin$ pip freeze
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Cython==0.28.2
docutils==0.14
idna==2.8
Kivy==1.10.1
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
pygame==1.9.4.dev0
Pygments==2.3.1
requests==2.21.0
urllib3==1.24.1
```

I think that error is related to something related to JAVA but I do not know what. I would appreciate your helps, and please, excuse my bad English.

I am working in Ubuntu 18

**UPDATE**
[Print Screen Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZSyR.png)

Comment: It looks like you're using OpenJDK 11, could you try using 8 instead?

Comment: Since JDK 9, The se.ee packages marked as deprecated so you need to include EE packages accordingly. Or just downgrade your JAVA to 9 or 8

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java.se.ee-summary.html

Answer (score 21):

Up until a few days ago if you had installed openjdk-11-jdk/jre from the Ubuntu repos you would have found it was actually a version of Java 10 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037646/why-is-openjdk-10-packaged-as-openjdk-11).

java.se.ee has been *deprecated* in Java 9, 10 and **removed** in Java 11 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)

Unfortunately there is no simple way to get the Android tools like sdkmanager or avdmanager running with Java 11 yet.

I was able to get buildozer running on Ubuntu again with Java 10:

- Download Java 10 Linux x64 JDK (.tar.gz) from http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/10
- Untar: `tar -xzvf jdk-10_linux-x64_bin_ri.tar.gz`
- Set PATH: `export PATH=/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 13):

was getting error License not accepted for SDK Build tools etc

solved by Installing

1. SDK Command Line Tools
2. Google Play licensing services

**in SDK Manager > SDK Tools**

helped me after getting frustrated for 2 hours, and hearing from everyone that only way is to downgrade Java

Comment: It should be mentioned that if you previously edited JAVA_OPTS using 'export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee''

Then you need to set it back to: export JAVA_OPTS = ''

Comment: Of all the answers. Yours was the one that worked. There was no option to accept the lisense without the license server apparently

Answer (score -6):

You can solve this error by downgrading Java or by executing the below command in your terminal.

```
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

Also, don't download the platform tools yourself, let buildozer take care of that.

If the above command doesn't work try deleting the buildozer files from your app and rebuilding your application.

Comment: I executed the command indicated above but does not work. I'm downloading the **Java 10 Linux x64 JDK (.tar.gz)** how indicated me @steve in the first answer and i wait thats work... I will actualizate the question, showing more information in a printscreen

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Comment: I made the mistake of executing your answer and now when I execute: (flutter doctor --android-licenses),.. I have this error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found. How can I revert this?

Comment: If somebody ends up here, just `unset JAVA_OPTS` to revert the exported variable