# Android license status unknown and a weird problem

Tags: java, android, flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

**I am running** flutter in windows 10. I previously had a running android setup. After cloning the flutter repo and updating path, I ran flutter doctor -v. The logs are below. Now after searching a bit for solving the problem, I came across to this solution from various stackoverflow answers: [Flutter.io Android License Status Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758849/flutter-io-android-license-status-unknown)
I at first executed this:
`set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee`

Though I don't know how to make it permanent. Then after running flutter doctor again, I came with another message, see log ###2

So it says Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[!] Android Studio (version 3.4). So I ran `flutter doctor --android-licenses` accordingly. And it gives another error, that is: 
`A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\imazi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update`

Well, so I ran `C:\Users\imazi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update` to update it. And it kinda updated successfully outputting `[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...`

So I thought the issue is solved and ran `flutter doctor` again but it seems that nothing has been changed the problem still remains. It is like a loop. I do everything and the problem remains as it is. The output of the last `flutter doctor` is in log ### 3

My java version is:

`10.0.2 2018-07-17`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)`

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)`

Please help.

!! also opened a github issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39637

### Logs

#### 1 flutter doctor -v

`O:\Flutter installation>flutter doctor -v`

```
 [âˆš] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Active code page: 1252
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)

â€¢ Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at O:\Work_Anon\Flutter installation\flutter
â€¢ Framework revision 20e59316b8 (6 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700    
â€¢ Engine revision fee001c93f
â€¢ Dart version 2.4.0
```

`[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)`

```
    **â€¢ Android SDK at C:\Users\imazi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    â€¢ Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    â€¢ Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    â€¢ Java binary at: O:\Work_Anon\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    â€¢ Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    **X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.****
```

`[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)`

```
â€¢ Android Studio at O:\Work_Anon\Android Studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
â€¢ Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
```

`[!] Connected device`

```
! No devices available
```

#### 2 flutter doctor after `set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee`

[âˆš] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Active code page: 1252

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)

`[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)` 
       ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
`[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)` 
       X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
       X   Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
`[!] Connected device` 
       ! No devices available

#### 3 last flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[âˆš] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Active code page: 1252

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-US)
`[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)`)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
`[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)`
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

`[!] Connected device`
    ! No devices available

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped as I ran `(your android_sdk folder exact path)\tools\bin\sdkmanager --licenses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem got solved after installing jdk 8 and setting JAVA_HOME accordingly this new jdk. Also in the sdkmanager.bat file, located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
I added the line `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221"`

No need to uninstall java 10. That solved the whole problem!

Comment: If someone else facing this issue not able to fix it, try my answer at a similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951338/6661043]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the flutter path is added.
Restart your system 
Then run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
accept all the licenses that appear 
again run `flutter doctor`
and check if the issue persists

Comment: Yes, the flutter path is added in the users variable. And after restarting it still remains the same. No licenses come for accepting

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall the java jdk from my system and then let my flutter doctor arise that error of " [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)"
and then followed the solution that flutter doctor was giving as it says to run the command " flutter doctor --android-licenses " and then type " y " as it says you to accept the licenses provided to solve this problem of "[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)" and then I again ran flutter doctor and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows, and solved by removing "\bin" from the JAVA_HOME value in system variables like this: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk"