# 'Android sdkmanager tool found, but failed to run' for flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, flutter-doctor

I've been trying to setup flutter with android studio on my laptop (Windows 11), and as I tried to agree to the android licenses the below error occured :
[image]

The first error in red says

> '(C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat):
> "ProcessException: Cannot find file specified'

Apologies for the Japanese.

Below are the SDK Platforms installed :
[image]

### **Solutions attempted :**

- Installing 'Android SDK Command-line tools (latest)' and 'Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)' as suggested by this thread : [Android SDK Tools option is missing from SDK Manager in Android Studio 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467477/android-sdk-tools-option-is-missing-from-sdk-manager-in-android-studio-3-6-1/60468907#60468907)

[image]

- Reinstalling Android studio
- Updating the sdkmanager
  [image]
- Checking PATH variables (JAVA_HOME in the System Variables set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351)
- Running the command myself, which has allowed me to agree to the licenses, however the issue persists with the android licenses when flutter doctor is run.
  [image: Running the exact command]

I've tried my best at scouring the internet for solutions, but any help would be much appreciated. I have made another question for the

> " 'git rev-parse HEAD' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command"

error here : [" 'git rev-parse HEAD ' is not recognized" error when flutter doctor, but still works normally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75103590/git-rev-parse-head-is-not-recognized-error-when-flutter-doctor-but-still)
I'm not sure if the two issues are connected, but if someone can also assist me on that issue I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 22):

It happen to me just now on my mac, after updating all sdk manager item to the latest version. Then, I downgrade the latest (version 11) Android SDK Commmad-Line Tools to version 10.

And it solve my problem.

[image: SDK Manager - SDK Tools]

Comment: How do you downgrade commandline-tools? I'm not getting any such option here in android studio

Comment: @pragmateek see my screenshot above, there is checkbox "Show Package Details". You need to checked it, then it will show all version available

Comment: worked like a charm, thank u

Comment: this is not the solution for me, i don't think its related anyway

Comment: @greendino either you can find the root cause, so it can be solved. Or, you can try a lot of possible solution to find one that match.

Comment: same to me, didn't work.

Comment: this is the solution for me, btw: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502#issuecomment-1384954269

Comment: @GlennPosadas you can re-post it to a new answer along with reference. Hope some one will be find it.

Answer (score 13):

I also stumbled to this problem when i upgrade Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

The old java_home is

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

The new java_home is

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

After setting correct environment variable flutter doctor setup license run smothly. Hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 5):

i have the same exact problem when running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
i solved it by re-set my android studio path for flutter with `flutter config --android-studio-dir=<android_studio_instalation_dir>`, in your case it would be

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Users\jerry\AppData\Local\Android"
```

and then just run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` again,
hope its solved

by the way i'm using latest Android SDK Command-line tools (11.0)

Comment: do not do this if you don't know what you doing, this is dangerous answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to at least restart your terminal after setting `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: It's enough to restart Windows Terminal and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after downgrading my commandline-tools, I still have the same issue.
What solved mine, Navigate to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools` then delete/remove all other commandline-tools except folder 10, then run flutter doctor --android-licenses.
I hope this work for you to. Thanks.

Comment: this sounds like your specific issue, android studio should've managed this automatically, mine only 10 after downgrading

Answer (score 0):

Solution for macOS go to;

/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents

copy & paste jbr file

change the file name of "jbr copy" to "jre"

run flutter doctor
problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Please try to

- install command line tools (latest)
- install Google Play licensing library

In the `SDK Tools` tab open the terminal and enter the command:

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

and if necessary run:

`flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin"`

then run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Accept the license when it prompts.

Answer (score -1):

Flutter doctor was posing the same licensing issue on Windows 10, even after I took the nifty cue here to manually run "sdkmanager.bat --licenses". The issue resolved when I [set the recommended environment variables](https://developer.android.com/tools#environment-variables) from SDK tools documentation. Flutter doctor reported some licenses were not accepted, but running "flutter doctor --android-licenses" took care of it.

Caveat, somewhat related: flutter doctor still chokes for two other issues:

> ✗ android-studio-dir = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.

The workaround typically offered for this issue has been to copy the contents of C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr into the C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre directory; alternatively to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable path to the jbr directory. This didn't work this time. I had to take the suggestion flutter doctor offered:

> Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
> flutter config --android-studio-dir=

Hope I don't need that, but flutter doctor thereafter reported favorably "No issues found!" All green checks. Finally.

Answer (score -2):

you need to check if your SDK version is old. In my case I had the same problem, and I fixed it by replacing the sdk version with the latest version.
Greetings