# Flutter doctor says I have licensing issues

Tags: java, flutter

I started getting a bunch of problems with android studio trying to recompile a program for the new 64bit requirements.  Started off giving me the strange error that JAVA_HOME environment variable was not set.  Strange since it worked for last compile.  There was a whole new version of Android studio so I ran all the upgrades and this is what I get when I try to run flutter doctor.  I suspect the problem is to do with jdk 13.0.1 having some differences but not sure what version I should try installing or maybe I am looking in wrong place.

c:\src\flutter>flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805], locale en-CA)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] Connected device

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

c:\src\flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
C:\Users\mctrivia\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

c:\src\flutter>C:\Users\mctrivia\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter.io Android License Status Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758849/flutter-io-android-license-status-unknown)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem.  Needed to sign up for an account with oracle and download Java 8 SDK

Answer (score 0):

Additional to having JavaJDK installed, installing `Android SDK Command-line tools`is required as well.

[image]