# Installing Flutter on Opensuse

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to install Flutter. I already downloaded the SDK, setup Android Studio and all necessary tools. The problem I am facing is regarding `Android License Status Unknown`. After reading up on the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16280). Running `flutter doctor -v` gives me the following information:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /home/zerocool/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (8 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/zerocool/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Following one of the comments from the github discussion (link above), I decided to copy all the required libraries manually and update the `CLASSPATH` variable in sdkmanager.sh script. Here are the files I downloaded following the suggestions [here](https://medium.com/@parsher/flutter-android-sdkmanager-update-with-jdk-12-ad8098165472). The files downloaded were:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users   69409 Oct 24  2009 activation.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users   27156 Dec 27  2018 istack-commons-runtime.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users  128076 Sep 12  2018 jaxb-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users  157148 May 18  2018 jaxb-core.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users 1017695 Jan  2  2019 jaxb-impl.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users  120605 Jan  2  2019 jaxb-jxc.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 zerocool users  903197 Jan  2  2019 jaxb-xjc.jar
```

After modifying the `CLASSPATH` I have the following:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jimfs-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/repository-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/gson-2.3.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-compress-1.12.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-12.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/guava-22.0.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/activation.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/jaxb-impll.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar:/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar
```

This did not solve the issue as expected and `flutter doctor -v` still complains about the license. Trying to run `sdkmanager --update` or `sdkmanager --android-licenses` throws a `NullPointerException` as given below:

```
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at /home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/package.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.repository.impl.meta.SchemaModuleUtil.marshal(SchemaModuleUtil.java:265)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.writePackage(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:275)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:169)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:124)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:518)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:397)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:365)
        at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:725)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:296)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
```

Not sure what should be my possible move after this. I am not ready to reinstall or remove my current JDK though (I'm afraid anything dependent on JDK 11 might crash if I remove it). Some assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you get RPM package in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The Java 1.8 is fine . Don't upgrade it
Have you run this?

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

If not do it and accept it's terms.

Also attend this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759126/10097848

Comment: @seyedliAghamali Trying to run the cmd you gave gives the following: `A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/home/zerocool/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update` . Trying to update sdkamanger results in `NullPointerException` as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

You should install jdk8. Download JAXB, which I think is incompatible