# Failed to accept Android licenses during installing flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to setup flutter on Windows, so I have been following the instructions in this [page](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) but when I try to agree on Android Licenses in cmd using `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at com.android.repository.api.RemoteListSourceProvider.create(RemoteListSourceProvider.java:51)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.<init>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:626)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getRepoConfig(AndroidSdkHandler.java:572)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:295)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.setSdkHandler(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:101)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.<init>(SdkManagerCli.java:95)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:74)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 8 more
```

I have been trying to solve this problem and did what I could, but I can't get rid from that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception)

Comment: Hey Ahmed, I think this is your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error

Answer (score 0):

For this error in Windows
first you need to set this
`set JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'`

after it use this command
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Please follow this link for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644766/8218866